# How to migrate data with newline characters from PostgreSQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, data-migration

I am attempting to migrate data from a PostgreSQL 11 database to SQL Server 2014. I am exporting the data from PostgreSQL by using the `pg_dump` tool to create a file of insert statements (using the `--inserts` flag). I am then attempting to process this file using the SQL Server `sqlcmd` tool to run those inserts against a SQL Server database (the tables in the SQL Server database are being created through a separate process - the migration file only contains the insert statements). Some of the column values in PostgreSQL have new line characters, and so when the file of insert statements is created some of the column values span multiple lines. For example:

```
INSERT INTO my.table( 123, 'safe value', 'Value with 
newline
character', 'another safe value');
```

All of the posts I have found recommend replacing the newlines with spaces before exporting the data from PostgreSQL. We have to keep the formatting in place though as the impacted strings are eventually being displayed in a GUI and the formatting is important.
Has anyone done this successfully in the past or have any suggestions on an approach? For instance, is it possible to somehow replace the newline characters with something else that would still preserve the formatting?  I haven't been able to find any options in the `pg_dump` command that would force it to export the content to a single line per statement, nor anything on the `sqlcmd` side to allow it to successfully process multi-line column values.  Pre-processing the inserts file before running it through sqlcmd is definitely an option, but I am not sure what changes to make to get `sqlcmd` to process it successfully.  Any help/advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: When I have to deal with something like that, I usually replace the newline with something else, but definitely not a space. You need something unique like `<#CrLf#>`, then you can replace it back to a newline when the data is moved.

Comment: That INSERT statement is valid standard SQL. Does this mean SQL Server can't cope with that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Specifically, the `sqlcmd` tool doesn't seem to be able to handle it. I think you are correct regarding SQL Server in general - I think that statement will work if run through SSMS.